# Add links to CSS :nth-child class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently stuck on how to assign links (internal `.html` links) to those `.button:nth-child()` class in CSS. The only way i knew to add links is via `<a href="">` in HTML, but it only works with the first `nth:child`, as you can see. Any solution (including Js), is very much appreciated.

**html**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check"/>
<label for="check" id="tog"></label>
<div id="menu">
    <a href="index.html">
        <span class="button"></span>
    </a>
    <span class="button"></span>
    <span class="button"></span>
    <span class="button"></span>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#check:checked ~ #menu .button:nth-child(1) 
{
    background-image: url("pictures/homeicon.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    top: 8.6%;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease;
    transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
#check:checked ~ #menu .button:nth-child(2) 
{
    background-image: url("pictures/portfolio.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    top: 17.1%;
    z-index: 90;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
#check:checked ~ #menu .button:nth-child(3) 
{
    background-image: url("pictures/abouticon.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    top: 25.7%;
    z-index: 80;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
#check:checked ~ #menu .button:nth-child(4) 
{
    background-image: url("pictures/connect.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    top: 34.2%;
    z-index: 70;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: Not certain what Question is? What do you mean by "assign links"?

Comment: where should the links link to? your code works for the first button because you just put the first button into an anchor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand of your question, one way to achieve this is by adding simple Javascript on each of your "button".

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
    <body>
       <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check"/>
        <label for="check" id="tog"></label>
        <div id="menu">
        <a href="index.html">
            <span class="button">button</span>
        </a>
        <span class="button" onclick="location.href='http://google.com';">button2</span>
        <span class="button" onclick="location.href='http://yahoo.com';">button2</span>
        <span class="button" onclick="location.href='http://duckduckgo.com';">button2</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `onclick="location.href='<some internal link>';"` allows you to redirect where you want.

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted! +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check"/>
 <label for="check" id="tog"></label>
 <div id="menu">
  <a href="index.html">
  <span class="button"></span>
  </a>
  <a href="index2.html">
  <span class="button"></span>
   </a>
```

And so on actually not clear about your question . Just add anchors to all the buttons right

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand about assign link as you said and what you want todo.
But i understand a litle what you want.
1. If you want give a links on all span with class button, you can give an anchors for all.
Here is example :

```
<div id="menu">
<a href="index.html">
<span class="button"></span>
</a>
<a href="index2.html">
<span class="button"></span>
</a>
<a href="index3.html"><span class="button"></span></a>
</div>
```

2. If you want give all span with url without anchor, 
Here is example :

```
    <div id="menu">
    <span class="button" onclick="wimdow.location.href='index1.html'"></span>
    <span class="button" onclick="wimdow.location.href='index2.html'"></span>
<span class="button" onclick="wimdow.location.href='index3.html'"></span>
    </div>
```

3. If you want add link via jquery, here is example :

   ```
   $("#menu").children($('.button')).eq(0).click(function(){
     $('.button').eq(0).html('<a href="index.html">Link</a>');
   });
   $("#menu").children($('.button')).eq(1).click(function(){
     $('.button').eq(1).html('<a href="index2.html">Link2</a>');
   });
   $("#menu").children($('.button')).eq(2).click(function(){
     $('.button').eq(2).html('<a href="index3.html">Link3</a>');
   });
   ```

   /* Or you can use this */

   ```
   $(".button").each(function(i,el){
     $(this).eq(i).html('<a href="index.html">Link'+i+'</a>');
   });
   ```